# Pandas: how to broadcast values by specific column rather than index when doing arithmetic operation?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I don't know if I make it clearly. I have two DataFrame:

```
In [1]: d1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'b':np.random.randint(1,9,9)})  
In [2]: d1
Out[2]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  7
2  1  5
3  2  2
4  2  8
5  2  1
6  3  5
7  3  5
8  3  8
In [3]: d2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'd':[7,2,9]})
In [4]: d2
Out[4]: 
   a  d
0  1  7
1  2  2
2  3  9
```

I want find the row in d2 with the same 'a' for every row in d1, and add this 'a''s 'd' in d2 to the 'b' of all corresponding rows in d1. In the other words, when doing the operation columns 'b' plus 'd', it will automatically broadcast just like 'a' is the index. The result may looks like:

```
   a  b
0  1  8
1  1  14
2  1  12
3  2  4
4  2  10
5  2  3
6  3  14
7  3  14
8  3  17
```

And I know `d1.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x - d2[d2['a']==x.iloc[0]['a']]['d'].values)`  can do this. But it seems too complicate.

Following code could do the same things. But I think it's not the right way to use index.

```
d1.set_index('a', inplace=True)
d2.set_index('a', inplace=True)
d1 + d2
d1.reset_index(inplace=True)
d2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not keep column 'a' as the index? Then you don't need to set/reset the index all the time.

Comment: @Rob Because 'a' may have duplicate values. Duplicate index could not use all features of pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or another way to do it:

```
df = d1.merge(d2, how='right', on='a')
df['sum'] = df.b + df.d
df
```

yielding (with `np.random.seed(0)`):

```
   a  b  d  sum
0  1  5  7   12
1  1  8  7   15
2  1  6  7   13
3  2  1  2    3
4  2  4  2    6
5  2  4  2    6
6  3  4  9   13
7  3  8  9   17
8  3  2  9   11
```

If you don't need all those extra columns it is easy to delete them with:

```
df.drop(['b','d'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change the index of `d1`.  Just make `d2` a Series with `a` as the index.  Then you can use the `map` method of Series:

```
d2 = d2.set_index('a').d
d1.b + d1.a.map(d2)
```